# On a sufficient condition for a closed morphism of schemes to be affine

Tags: algebraic-geometry

Let $f \colon X \to Y$ be a *closed* morphism of schemes (i.e., the image of any closed subset of $X$ under $f$ is closed in $Y$). Let $y \in Y$. Consider the following assertions:

> (i) There is an affine open subscheme $U$ of $X$ such that $f^{-1}(y) \subset U$.
>
> (ii) For every open subscheme $U'$ of $X$ satisfying $f^{-1}(y) \subset U'$, there is an affine open subscheme $U$ of $X$ such that $f^{-1}(y) \subset U \subset U'$.
>
> (iii) $f$ is "affine near y", i.e. there is an open subscheme $V$ of $Y$ such that $y \in V$ and the restriction $f^{-1}(V) \to V$ of $f$ is an affine morphism.

I know that (ii) implies (iii) (this is a proposition contained in the more recent edition of *EGA I*; the proof is easy, see below).

### Questions

- Does (i) imply (iii)? (Exercise 12.3 in *Algebraic Geometry I* by Görtz and Wedhorn asks you to prove just that implication.)
- Does (i) imply (ii)?

I see no reason why the answer to any of these questions should be "yes" but I have not been able to produce a counterexample and would appreciate any help.

### Proof of $(ii) \Rightarrow (iii)$

(Taken from *EGA I*, 2nd ed.) Let $V'$ be an affine open neighborhood of $y$ in $Y$. By (ii), there is an affine open subscheme $U$ of $X$ such that $f^{-1}(y) \subset U \subset f^{-1}(V')$. Thus, $f$ induces a morphism $g \colon U \to V'$ which is affine by construction (because both $U$ and $V'$ are affine). As $f$ is closed,
$$V := \bigl( Y \setminus f(X \setminus U) \bigr) \cap V'$$
is an open subscheme of $Y$; by construction, $y \in V$, $V \subset V'$ and $f^{-1}(V) \subset U$. Thus, the restriction $f^{-1}(V) \to V$ is a base change of the affine morphism $g \colon U \to V'$ and, as a consequence, affine itself.

(Note that this proof seems to break down if we assume only (i) instead of (ii). Indeed, why should *affine* $V'$ and $U$ having the desired properties exist?)